# Taking a Picture, and saving it to Disk in a Windows 8 Metro-style App

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I am ABLE to take a picture, but I am having trouble saving it to one of the `KnownFolders`.
Yes, I have declared the Picture Library Access Capability in Package.appxmanifest.

```
var ui = new CameraCaptureUI();

ui.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(4, 3);
StorageFile file = await ui.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

if (file != null)
{
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.SetSource(stream);
    Photo.Source = bitmap;
    StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
    var result = await file.CopyAsync(storageFolder, "tps.jpg");
}
```

The code stops on the last line.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Along with @shenhengbin's advice: Are you adding the `async` keyword next to the Access Modifier on the method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need declare the file types!

- In the Declarations tab, choose File Type Associations from Available
  Declarations and click Add.
- Under Properties, set the Name property to image.
- In the Supported File Types box, add .jpg as a supported file type by
  entering .jpg in the FileType field.